# Why short circuiting gains priority over increment in C?

Tags: c, side-effects

```
void main()
{
  int i=-3, j=2, k=0,m;
  m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
  printf("\n%d %d %d %d",i,j,k,m);
}
```

This snippet prints -2 3 0 1 but why not -2 3- 1 1 .
Eventhough the ++ operator of k has precedence over logical operator, why k is not incremented because of short circuiting? 
   More generally how to apply precendence when there are logical operators and side effects
involved?

Comment: stop thinking of "precedence" as "order of evaluation"

Answer (score 1):

*Short circuiting* here means if the left operand of the logical `AND` operator `&&` evaluates to `false`, then it won't evaluate its right operand. Similarly, if the left operand of the logical `OR` operator `||` evaluates to `true`, then its right operand is not evaluated. That's because, then the result is not affected whatever the right operand might evaluate to.

Also, `&&` has higher precedence than `||` operator.

Therefore, the expression `m = ++i && ++j || ++k;` is equivalent to

```
m = (++i) && (++j || ++k);
```

The left operand `++i` evaluates to `-2` which is `true` (non-zero). Therefore, now the second expression `(++j || ++k)` is evaluated. The left operand of `||` operator is `++j` which evaluates to `3`, i.e., `true`. This means the right operand of `||`, i.e., the expression `++k` is not evaluated.

Therefore, only the sub-expressions `++i` and `++j` get evaluated. The whole expression evaluates to `1` as it is `true`.

Comment: is it not the && operator has more precedence?

Comment: @muru yes, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the main function (unless you use ancient Turbo C) should return `int`.

Secondly, a decent compiler (clang for me) complains about the dubious expression:

```
clang++ -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel ls.cpp 
ls.cpp:5:11: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
  m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
      ~~~~^~~~~~ ~~
ls.cpp:5:11: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
  m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
          ^
      (         )
1 warning generated.
```

Thirdly, let's see the assembly output:

```
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 8], -3       # this is i
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 12], 2       # this is j
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 16], 0       # this is k

    mov eax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]      # this is i++
    add eax, 1
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 8], eax
    cmp eax, 0                        # is i++ == 0?
    je  .LBB0_2
# BB#1:                               # no, i++ is NOT 0
    mov al, 1
    mov ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 12]     # this is j++
    add ecx, 1
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 12], ecx     
    cmp ecx, 0
    mov byte ptr [rbp - 21], al       # store al as a flag somewhere else
                                      # it will be the final result of the operation
    jne .LBB0_3                       # if j++ was NOT zero, go down to LBB0_3


.LBB0_2:                             # Yes, i++ is 0. Did you remark that
                                         # it didn't increment j in this case?
                                         # but it needs to increment k since the first
                                         # part of the OR evaluated to false.
    mov eax, dword ptr [rbp - 16]    # This is k++
    add eax, 1
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 16], eax
    cmp eax, 0                       # is c++ 0?
    setne   cl                       # if yes, set cl as a flag to 1
    mov byte ptr [rbp - 21], cl # 1-byte Spill

    # and here we get if j++ was not zero, 
    # so did you remark that k was not incremented?
.LBB0_3:
    mov al, byte ptr [rbp - 21] # 1-byte Reload
    lea rdi, qword ptr [.L.str]
    and al, 1
    movzx   ecx, al
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 20], ecx

    # there goes the printf    
    mov esi, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
    mov edx, dword ptr [rbp - 12]
    mov ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 16]
    mov r8d, dword ptr [rbp - 20]
    mov al, 0
    call    printf
```

Comment: Do you really think that dumping assembly in front of someone who doesn't understand basic operators would help?

Comment: Together with explanations I think it's a good point to start. But let's see what the future will bring.